How to exclude lines where a data is being referenced in another column SQL
I need help with a problem to exclude matching rows.
I have a table that has multiple columns,this table refers to a travel, the rows can contain data to a full travel, the first part of the travel or the second part of the travel.
Table example
1



SC_ID
REF
SOL_ID




100.500

350


100.501
AAAA
390


100.502
350
500


100.503

777



In this table, "SC_ID" and "SOL_ID" are indepentent numbers and "REF" might containt the reference value of the "SOL_ID" of another line (to link the first part of a travel with the second).
This column, "REF", can be null, can be whatever or can be the "SOL_ID" number.
What I want is a select statement for atable where all the lines that have a reference "REF to another "SOL_ID" being excluded, together with all lines that are referenced by their "SOL_ID" in a "REF".
Based on the example table: SC_ID 100.500 and 100.502 should be excluded of the select view because they are referenced.
And the result should be only:
2



SC_ID
REF
SOL_ID




100.501
AAAA
390


100.503

777



To summary what I want to not show:
If the "REF" is null but the "SOL_ID" of that line is in any other "REF" in the table, this line should be excluded from the select.
If the "REF" is present, and it is a "SOL_ID" in the table, this line should be excluded from the select.
To summary what I want to show:
All data with null "REF" that have their "SOL_ID" not present in the "REF" column of another data.
All data with "REF" values that are not a "SOL_ID" in the table.
I've tried doing self joins, left join...
But the problem is that the second part of the travel keep showing (row with REF with SOL_ID of the previous travel) or none value at all. Or maybe it's just a mess because it's one table for all...
SELECT * 
FROM travel_history th1 
JOIN travel_history th2 on th1."SOL_ID" = th2."SOL_ID"
WHERE
(th1."REF" is null and th1."SOL_ID" not in th2."REF")
and
th1."REF" not in th2."SOL_ID";


Please don’t link to images. Update your question to provide 1) table definitions/DDL 2) enough example data to illustrate the possible scenarios (formatted as tables) 3) the result you want to achieve based on that sample data. If you do this then I’m guessing that a lot of your descriptive text would be unnecessary and you could significantly reduce the length of your question

This correction should produce the results you want
SELECT * 
FROM travel_history th1 
--INNER JOIN travel_history th2 on th1.SOL_ID = th2.SOL_ID
WHERE
  th1.SOL_ID not in (SELECT REF from travel_history)
  AND
  th1.REF not in  (SELECT SOL_ID from travel_history)

OR
--Simplified self join
SELECT th1.* 
FROM travel_history th1 
LEFT JOIN travel_history th2 on th1.SOL_ID = th2.REF OR th1.REF = th2.SOL_ID
WHERE
  th2.SC_ID is null

SQL-Server fiddle example



SC_ID
REF
SOL_ID




100.501
AAAA
390


100.503

777




Thanks for the help, the simplified version did the trick with a few changes.

Thanks for the help!
The first version did not work, I believe because I have to do castings and the " th1.REF not in" line came back empty.
The simplified version did the trick.
I just got to do some casting since SOL_ID is bigint and REF is a varchar, I also had to change the SC_ID to SOL_ID.
--Code that I used
SELECT th1.*
FROM travel_history th1
LEFT JOIN travel_history th2 on cast(th1.SOL_ID as varchar) = th2.REF 
OR th1.REF = cast(th2.SOL_ID as varchar)
WHERE
th2.SOL_ID is null

